# Getting extra print from environment? Why am I getting "are\VMware Player\bin\"

Tags: c

when I get the document I get "are\VMware Player\bin" as extra no idea how to fix this.
I'm running in Clion , windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char* name;/*name of macro*/
    char* word; /* array to store */
    struct Node* next;/* next in line */

}Node;

Node* createNode(const char* word, const char* name) {
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); /*mallocing space */
    newNode->word = malloc(sizeof(word));/*free this, in the function freeList*/
    newNode->name = malloc(sizeof(name));
    if (newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->name = strcpy(newNode->name,name);
        strcpy(newNode->word, word);/*copy the word to a list data */

        newNode->next = NULL;/*to point to null as an indication to end of the list*/
    }
    return newNode;
}

Node* insertNode(Node* head, const char* word, const char* name) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return createNode(word, name);
    } else {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {/*locating the last list memb*/
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = createNode(word, name);/*after locating we create*/

        return head;
    }
}

void freeList(Node* head) {
    Node* current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        Node* temp = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

char* removeWord(const char* sentence, const char* word) {
    int sentence_len = strlen(sentence);
    int word_len;
    if(word!=NULL)
    word_len = strlen(word);
    else
        perror("word is equal to NULL");


    /* Create a copy of the sentence*/
    char* copy = malloc((sentence_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(copy, sentence);

    char* p = copy;

    while ((p = strstr(p, word)) != NULL) {
        memmove(p, p + word_len, strlen(p + word_len) + 1);
    }

    copy[sentence_len + 1] = '\0';

    return copy;
}

void replace_word(char* str, int index, char* new_word) {
    int len_str = strlen(str);
    if(new_word==NULL) perror("Word is null");
    int len_new_word = strlen(new_word);
    char *word = NULL;
    int i;

    /* Find start of word*/
    for (i = index; i < len_str && (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n'); ++i);

    if(i==len_str){ /* If end of string is reached */
        printf("No words found.\n");
        return;
    }

/* Allocate memory for word and copy characters until we reach whitespace or newline*/
    int j=0;
    while(i+j<len_str && str[i+j]!=' ' && str[i+j]!= '\n'){
        j++;
    }

    word=(char*) malloc((j+1)*sizeof(char));  /* Add one extra byte to store null terminator*/

    if(word==NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        return ;
    }

    memcpy(word,&str[i],j*sizeof(char));
    word[j]='\0';  /* Null terminate the extracted word*/

/* Replace old word with new in original string*/
    memmove(&str[index+len_new_word],&str[index+j],(len_str-index-j)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(&str[index],new_word,len_new_word*sizeof(char));

    str[len_str - j + len_new_word] = '\0';

    free(word); /* Free dynamically allocated memory */

}


void remove_substring(char* str, int start_index, int end_index) {
    int len_str = strlen(str);

    if(start_index<0 || end_index>=len_str || start_index>end_index){ /* Check for invalid input */
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return;
    }

// Shift all characters after the matched substring to left by length of matched substring
    memmove(&str[start_index],&str[end_index+1],(len_str-end_index)*sizeof(char));
}



void removeComments(char* str) {
    int inComment = 0;/*flag set to false*/
    char* src = str;/* so we don't lose the address*/
    char* dest = str;

    while (*src != '\0') {/*not null*/
        if (*src == ';' && !inComment) {/*in the line we find ; + incomment flag is set to false*/
            inComment = 1; /* Start of comment*/
        } else if (*src == '\n' && inComment) {/*else we will look for /n or untill we get to one*/
            inComment = 0; /*End of comment*/
            src++; /*we move src like in array manner to the next slot*/
            continue;/*we don't want to continue the rest of the code*/
        }
        /* copies the character at the src pointer to the memory location pointed to by dest=destion.
         * It then increments both the src and dest pointers.*/
        if (!inComment)/*in case inComment is true means we need to continue untill */
            *dest++ = *src;/*firstly we copy the address of src to dest and after wards we incement dest which in return incements src*/
        src++;/*moves the src pointer to the next character in the input string.
 * This process ensures that the character is copied and both pointers are correctly advanced for the next iteration.*/

    }

    *dest = '\0'; /* Terminate the resulting string*/
}




void removeEmptyLines(char* str) {
    char* src = str;
    char* dest = str;
    int inLine = 0;

    while (*src != '\0') {
        if (*src == '\n' || *src == '\t') {
            if (!inLine) {
                src++;
                continue; /* Skip the empty line or line with only tabs*/
            }
            inLine = 0; /* Reset the inLine flag for the next line*/
        } else if (*src != ' ' && *src != '\t') {
            inLine = 1; /*Set the inLine flag if a non-whitespace character is encountered*/
        }

        *dest++ = *src++;
    }

    *dest = '\0'; /*Terminate the resulting string*/
}

int find_string_position(char* text, char* target) {
    int len_text = strlen(text);
    int len_target = strlen(target);

    // Loop through every character in the text
    for (int i = 0; i <= len_text - len_target; ++i) {
        if (strncmp(&text[i], target, len_target) == 0) { // Check if this is the substring we want to find
            if((text[i+len_target] == ' ' || text[i+len_target] == '\n') && (text[i-1] == ' ' || text[i-1] == '\n' || i-1 < 0))
                return i;// Return position of match
        }
    }

    return -1; /*If no occurrences are found*/
}

void find_string_position2( char* text, char* target, char* toReplace)
{
    char* temp = NULL;
    int position = 0;
    int i = 0;

    temp = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, text);

    while(*temp != '\0')
    {
        if((position = find_string_position(temp, target)) > -1)
        {
            //printf("Found '%s' at position %d.\n", target, position);
            replace_word(text, position + (strlen(toReplace)-2)*i, toReplace);

            memset(temp, '0', position + strlen(target));
            i++;
        }else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    free(temp);
}

/* extractWords functions purpose is to start extracting the desires words from point 1 untill point 2.*/
Node* extractWords(const char* code, const char* startWord, const char* endWord) {
    char *word;
    char* name;
    int counter=0;
    word = NULL;
    name = malloc(sizeof(code));
    Node* list = NULL;
    const char* start = strstr(code, startWord/*will be created from main*/);

    if (start == NULL) {
        printf("Start word not found!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    start += strlen(startWord);

    const char* end = strstr(start, endWord);
    if (end == NULL) {
        printf("End word not found!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while(end != NULL)
    {

        word = removeWord(start, end);
        if(sscanf(word, "%s",name)==1) {
            word = removeWord(word, name);
            list = insertNode(list, word, name);/*saving the marco's name*/
        }else perror("Problem with allocating name for Node");

        printf("%s\n", word);
        int endPos = find_string_position(code, endWord) + strlen(endWord) - 1;
        int startPos = find_string_position(code, startWord);
        remove_substring(code, startPos, endPos);
        start = strstr(code, startWord/*will be created from main*/);

        if(start != NULL)
        {
            start += strlen(startWord);
            end = strstr(start, endWord);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //freeList(list);
    return list;
}

/*int main() {
    char text[] = "Hello world ! Welcome world to C programming wordworld world c world.";
    char target[] = "world";

    find_string_position2(text, target);
}*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* fw;
    int i;
    long length = 0;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    Node* getList = NULL;
    Node* current = NULL;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        perror("The compiler needs an input of files");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! Couldn't open %s", argv[i]);
            continue;
        }

        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (fp);
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (length + 1);

        if (buffer)
            fread (buffer, 1, length, fp);

        if(fp != NULL)
            fclose(fp);

        buffer[length] = '\0';

        /* check that buffer isn't null */
      if (buffer)
        {
            argv[i][strlen(argv)-1] = 'm';

            if((fw = fopen(argv[i], "w")) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Couldn't create the file for %s", argv[i]);
                continue;
            }

            getList = extractWords(buffer, "mcro", "endmcro");
            current = getList;
            removeComments(buffer);

            while(current != NULL)
            {
                find_string_position2(buffer, current->name, current->word);
                current = current->next;
            }

            removeEmptyLines(buffer);

            fprintf(fw, "%s", buffer);

            if(fw != NULL)
                fclose(fw);

            free(buffer);
            freeList(getList);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Error allocating memory");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the document the main arg gets:

```
mcro m1
sohel sohel
sohe,
sohel
endmcro

mcro m2
nat nat
nate
  nate
nat
endmcro

m1


m2


m1
;comment

;Hello world
```

and the return document I get is:

```
sohel sohel
sohe,
sohel
 nat nat
nate
  nate
nat
 sohel sohel
sohe,
sohel
are\VMware Player\bin\
```

Comment: There is a lot of code; try to minimize it.  It's most like out-of-bound access or missing `\0` terminator.  Not sure what compiler you are using `gcc -fanalyzer` will probably be helpful, and on Linux valgrind.

Comment: There's no need for `if(fp != NULL)` or `if(fw != NULL)`. You check whether `fopen()` returns `NULL` when you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it I changed a relloc to malloc and it worked somehow no idea why it causes it or where I exactly changed it but whatever works works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).